# Kendo Grid - Make a cell editable/uneditable for each row dynamically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid where the COR ABA No. may or may not be editable, depending on a value in the first column. So, if NOC Code=='C01', then COR ABA No. is editable, otherwise it is not.

[image]

I have achieved this by adding the Edit event on the columns and in that edit handler disabling the HTML input Kendo creates, when no editing is allowed. (In the grid definition, I have Editable(true) to start). I want instead to do this by doing the logic check in the DataBound event for the grid. That is, after all data is bound, iterate over the data, determine when the column should NOT be editable, and prevent this somehow. My idea is to simply remove the click handler that I ASSUME Kendo adds for a cell when using Editable(true) as stated above. Is this the way? Or how? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest another way, instead call closeCell() on edit event, if you do not want to allow the user to edit the cell. In doing so, the cell will not display an input when the user clicks it to edit it.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "id" },
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: {
          "id": { type: "number" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  editable: "incell",
  toolbar:["create"],
  edit: function(e) {
    if (!e.model.isNew() && e.container.index() == 0) {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      grid.closeCell();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, closeCell was what I needed.

Comment: @Scott thats the same I have suggested you yesterday, I think. haha anyway, good to know it works.