# How to Edit specific bound column in kendo grid with jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We have the requirement to edit a specific Kendo grid column if model flag status is "yes". It has to done by using a jquery function.

Ex code:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Qty).Width(120).ClientTemplate("..some events and function data values----");
columns.Bound(p => p.oldQty).Width(120);
columns.Bound(p => p.id);
```

I want to edit the QTY column alone based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ClientTemplate of that column, you can pass the column value to a function where you can alter how the value is displayed, like so:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Qty).Width(120).ClientTemplate("#=myNewFunction(Qty)#");
```

then your js function:

```
    function myNewFunction(valueToEdit) {
        //ALTER valueToEdit based on your condition here
        return "new updated value";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.also suggest please how  to make QTY cell is not editable.If authorization flag is No.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20881973/493557 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241454/493557.  If you want to edit your original question and add that additional question, I will update my answer as well and you can mark it as the correct answer